# Can I use touch-to-focus on my Canon 80D with focus set to the AF-On button?

Tags: canon, autofocus, camera-settings, canon-80d, back-button-autofocus

My Canon 80D has a touch to focus function. It works on auto mode, but I have changed my auto focus function to AF-ON button from half shutter button — and it doesn't now. I changed my auto focus function back to half shutter button and the touch to focus feature works.

But I want my autofocus to AF-ON button. Can I use touch to focus feature and back focus button at the same time?

Comment: Possible ? https://youtu.be/3vQwZzbhzXs

Comment: Nope. This video does not cover how to touch focus. This video is no where near my question. But thanks.

Comment: *"It works on auto mode."* Auto **what** mode? Auto exposure? Auto focus? Auto selection of AF point? Auto ISO? Auto white balance?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one manual I find [here](http://www.dummies.com/photography/cameras/canon-camera/use-touch-shutter-canon-eos-80d/) which cover your question:

1. Enable the Touch Control option on Setup Menu 3. You can select
   Standard or Sensitive as the menu option; your choice determines how
   firm of a touch you need to use to get the touchscreen to respond.
2. Shift to Live View mode. Just move that Live View switch to the
   camera position and then press the Start/Stop button.
3. Look for the Touch Shutter icon in the lower-left corner of the
   monitor. By default, the touch-shutter feature is turned off, so the
   word Off appears with the icon.
4. Tap the icon to toggle the touch shutter function on. You also can
   turn the feature on via Shooting Menu 5 (Live View).
5. Compose your shot and then tap the subject on the monitor. If you’re
   focusing manually, the camera releases the shutter to take the
   picture. For autofocusing, the camera attempts to focus on the spot
   you tapped. If it’s successful, it releases the shutter to take the
   picture. If focus can’t be achieved, the camera won’t record the
   photo.